# laravel website is not working on first loading

Tags: php, laravel

Hey i am working on a script in laravel and i install it correctly but when i try to navigate the website it is giving me 500 error but when i reload the page it works fine.
Here is mey .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine  On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Here is the log file

```
'[2021-12-20 14:16:57] codecanyon.ERROR: Allowed memory 
 size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6061440 
  bytes) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] 
  (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 
    0): Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried 
    to allocate 6061440 bytes) at  /  h   ome/admin/public_html/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervent 
    .ion/Image/Gd/Decoder.php:32)
   [stacktrace]
   #0 {main}
   "}'
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. Check the webserver and laravel error logs in case there are more hints as to might actually be the issue. It might not be an issue with .htaccess

Comment: will clearing the browser catch will do the work?

Comment: are you getting any error message in log file ?

Comment: you should check your laravel.log file first

Comment: I edit the questions with my logfile @arifulislam

Comment: your memory limit in php.ini file have been exceeeded. You should increase it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your answers. I solved it. My memory limit in php.ini file had exceeeded, By increasing it solves the problem.

Answer (score -3):

working .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```